# ssh shortcut is attempting to connect to a different ip

Tags: server, ssh, shortcut-keys

I am trying to ssh (with shortcut via .ssh/config) into an EC2 instance from my MacOSX and observing a strange behavior. That is when attempting to SSH to a IP `XYZ` I am getting a failed message saying

`ssh: connect to host ABC port 22: Operation timed out`

I am wondering why it could be attempting to connect to IP `ABC` when I am attempting to ssh into IP `XYZ`

my `.ssh/config` looks something as below

```
Host xyz-prod
    HostName XYZ
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/XYZ.pem
```

and the command I am using to ssh is `ssh xyz-prod`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have more than one `Host xyz-prod` in your `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: What IP does host `XYZ` resolve to? (`host XYZ`) What does that IP resolve to?

Comment: @PerlDuck no. I have just one entry that is `XYZ`

Comment: @waltinator not sure how to figure that out? but `XYZ` is a public Ip address of an AWS EC2 server. Also I am able to ssh using the regular `ssh -i` command.